# jquery form submit changing values to whole form

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery I have

```
$('form#submit :input').val("");
```

Which is changing the value of the form to empty after success:. Problem is that its changing every value of everything in the form.

```
<form id="submit" method="post" name="submit" action=""><input type="hidden" name="word" id="word" value="<?=$word?>"><textarea name="sentence" id="sentence" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size:2em; vertical-align:bottom" /></form>
```

So the textarea and submit button are being blanked out. I want the textarea to blank out, but not the button. Is there a way to just specify the button?

Comment: `$("form#submit")[0].reset();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
$('form#submit :input').not('input[type="submit"]').val("");
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ag6z9/)**

Comment: PERFECT! as usual stackoverflow community is freakin awesome :)